# Post Increment in do while loop if condition is TRUE (BEST WAY?)

Tags: c++, c, increment, do-while, post-increment

It is quite simple, indeed.

```
int main()
{
    int n,i,j;
    n = 20;
    i = 0;
    char ch[8];

    do
    {
        ch[i] = (n%2) + '0';
        n /= 2;
        // SIMPLE WAY
        if(n != 0)
            i++;
    }
    while(n != 0);

    for(j=0; j<=i; j++)
    {
        printf("%c",ch[i-j]);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

But i don't like this WAY

I tried the below WAY but code is bad

```
int main()
{
    int n,i,j;
    n = 20;
    i = 0;
    char ch[8];

    do
    {
        ch[i] = (n%2) + '0';
        n /= 2;
    }
    while(n != 0 && i++); // THIS

    for(j=0; j<=i; j++)
    {
        printf("%c",ch[i-j]);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

How to get the value incremented only when the loop is true with BEST WAY?
OR just correct 2nd way `while(n != 0 && i++)`

Comment: What do you mean by "best way"? (...and why is it always capitalized?)

Comment: **best way:** I do not like normal ways
That's why I always look for genius and fairly easy ways

**always capitalized:** Draw attention

Comment: What do you have against the "normal way"?  Perhaps it's the "normal way" for a reason?

Comment: for (int n = 20; n > 0; n /= 2)  ch[i++] = (n%2) + '0';  followed by for (int j = 0; j < i; j++)

Comment: @HansPassant [`for (int n = ...; n > 0`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53036012/post-increment-in-do-while-loop-if-condition-is-true-best-way/53036133?noredirect=1#comment92972941_53036012) has different print out when [n==0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53036012/post-increment-in-do-while-loop-if-condition-is-true-best-way/53036133?noredirect=1#comment92972591_53036057).

Comment: I could point out that 20 isn't 0, but that would be entirely too duh.  Never slows down anybody in the [c++] tag though, odd isn't it?  Just address the author to point out corner-cases.

Comment: Mohammed Esafi, Do you want a C or C++ answer? - best to chose only one.

Comment: @chux C or C++ I thought there will not be any difference

Comment: The _best_ answer can differ between languages.  Tagging a question as `C` and `C++` when only one is really needed attracts down-votes and votes-to-close for being too broad or unclear.

Comment: Even stack overflow??? There's already a billion of tutorials that have C/C++ tags, polutting C/C++ ecosystem with cancer, and it's spreading even to SO? Come on now. SO should just prevent users from putting more than one distinct programming language or we'll have why my C code doesn't compile in g++ all over again.

Comment: @pur: There are valid reasons to tag a question with both C and C++. [Proposed update to C and C++ tag usage wikis](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/374306/1889329) has more information, in case you care.

Comment: This question has nothing to do with C++ so I don't care. I know that there's topics that could be *tag as many languages as possible* worthy, but we don't tag all programming languages, do we? Imagine if someone tagged every single language that has arrays when the problem they were having was something to do with arrays in C. Don't you think it's just kind of silly? Might aswell start tagging `C` `C++` and `C#` every time you have problems with C. Makes no sense whatsoever. But wait, they all have C in them, must be same thing of course!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you can always do:

```
do {
   // code
} while(n != 0 && ++i);
```

This way, `i` is incremented right after the first part of `&&` evaluates to True, and `&&` is applied to `n != 0` and the updated version of `i`.

Comment: but if it starts with -5?

Comment: @АлексейНеудачин, it doesn’t in the OP’s case

Answer (score 6):

> How to get the value incremented only when the loop is true with BEST WAY?
>   OR just correct 2nd way while(n != 0 && i++)

I recommend neither approach.

There is no need for a special test to see if code should increment `i`.

```
do {
  ch[i] = (n%2) + '0';
  n /= 2;
  i++;
} while(n != 0);
// Just decrement after the loop
i--;

for(j=0; j<=i; j++) {
    printf("%c",ch[i-j]);
}
```

Alternatively do not decrement at all

```
do {
  ch[i] = (n%2) + '0';
  n /= 2;
  i++;
} while(n != 0);

for(j=0; j<i; j++) {
  printf("%c",ch[i-1-j]);
}
```

Or use a `do ... while` for printing also.

```
do {
  ch[i++] = (n%2) + '0';
  n /= 2;
} while(n);

do {
  printf("%c",ch[--i]);
} while (i);
```

---

Notes:

`char ch[8];` is too small for an `int` outside the range `[-255 ... 255]`. For 32-bit `int`, use `char ch[32];` or wider.  In general, use  `char ch[sizeof(int) * CHAR_BIT];`

`ch[i] = (n%2) + '0';` will certainly incur unexpected results when `n < 0`.  Consider `unsigned` types instead.

Comment: Your second snippet is the best solution of all here. No need for hacky workarounds in this problem.

Comment: This is the right answer. Loop termination does not depend on the value of `i`, so `i` should not be mentioned in the termination test.

Comment: it depends of style

Answer (score 1):

In C++, you might do:

```
std::cout << std::bitset<8>(n); // 00010100 for n = 20
```

if leading `0` are ok.

Answer (score -1):

It can be like this:

```
int n = 20;
int i = 7;
char ch[] = "00000000";
while (n) // if n already = 0 then do nothing
{
    ch[i--] = (n % 2) + '0'; // assign then increment
    n /= 2;                // shift to right same as n >>= 1;
}
printf ("%08s", ch);
```

Comment: When `0<n<10`, this answer leads to calling `printf("%c",ch[1]);` and `printf("%c",ch[0])`, yet `ch[1]` never assigned.

Comment: Yes, but question about only this part of code. Of course good practice is initializing variable for exemple `char ch[8] = {0};` .And last part of code can be more simple like `printf("%08s",ch);`

Comment: 1) Even with initializing, then code is still first printing `printf("%c",0);` for   `n < 128`.  2) `printf("%08s",ch);` is undefined behavior when all 8 `char` are written as `ch` is not then a _string_ as it lacks a _null character_.  IAC, `"%08s"`  prints in the wrong order as desired.

Answer (score -2):

```
do
{ .......... }while(n && i++ ? 1 : n);
```

this stuff about `&&` actions called short-circuit evaluation

Comment: This does not answer any of the questions that are asked.